# <option> not append in <select> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried to append `<option>` inside `<select>` using javascript by parsing data from XMl. Data parsed from xml properly,but it is not appending in `<select>`.

Also I want to show option as (image+text) format. How to do this....

**My HTML code:**

```
<form style="margin:20px 0">
    <p>
        <select id='mySelect' multiple="multiple" style="width:370px">
        </select>
    </p>

</form>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "newpersonal1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var select = $('#mySelect');
            $(xml).find('value').each(function(){
                 var title = $(this).find('name').text();
                 alert(title);
                 select.append("<option value='"+title+"'>"+title+"</option>");         
            });                 
        }
    });
});
```

How to fix this issue and add image in select `<option>`.

Comment: As far as I know you can't have images in `<option>` elements. You can use CSS to set a background image but it doesn't work in all browsers. Or you can simulate a `<select>` element with nested `<div>` elements or a `<ul>` or something.

Comment: please show what your title string looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make additional steps when you deal with "filter and multiselect plugin" in your way.

It mimics the select object, hiding the original one and creating the set of button and span elements. It uses the original one only at the moment of initialization.

So, you have to call function refresh() as soon as you update the original select tag with additional options.

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me.

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "newpersonal1.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var select = $('#mySelect');
        var options = '';
        $(xml).find('value').each(function(){
             var title = $(this).find('name').text();
             options += "<option value='" + title + "'>" + title + "</option>";                         
        });             
        select.html(options);
        $("#mySelect").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
    }
  });   
});
```

I noticed that the xml file does not load in chrome when html run from a local folder.
But it does work on a server.

Mark as answer if helpful.
Cheers

Comment: It is working properly when using normal select box. i have tried with filter and multiselect plugin from http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter. if i use these, options not appending...i dont know the reason....in the filter plugin sample static data only passed.i tried dynamic data....

Comment: Move the code for invoking the multiselect plugin on the dropdowns after the ajax call success. Like this:

In my previous answer, after this line of code:
select.html(options);
add the below line of code:   $("#mySelect").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
Mark as answer if helpful. I have modified my answer to include this edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* that your `title` string is malformed and requires escaping.

Concatenating strings isn't a good way to create elements unless you're absolutely sure the values can't contain any special characters.  A better approach therefore would be:

```
$('<option>', { val: title, text: title }).appendTo(select);
```

I'd note that it's not actually necessary to specify a value in an `<option>` tag if the desired value is the same as the text contained within the option.

Comment: It is also not working...Actually i have tried filter plugin from http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter. In that <option> having static data..i tried to append dynamic data parsing from XML...if i remove the multiselect plugins data appending properly...but if i add the plugins data  not appending...

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you,

```
   var selectList = "", title = ""; 
   $(xml).find('value').each(function(){ 
    title = $(this).find('name').text(); 
    selectList += "<option value='" + title + "'>" + title + "</option>";
   });
   $('#mySelect').html(selectList);
```

this code is work in my case don't know for you....