# Select option can not .append() properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, append

I have faced the issue for my project search area. I have used the dynamic drop down list.

My Jquery Code:

```
   <script>
     $('#vehicle_make').on('change',function(e){        
     var model_id = e.target.value;
     $.get('/ajax-get-subcat?model_id=' + model_id,function(data){
        $('.vehicle_model').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,areaObj){
        $('.vehicle_model').append('<option                        
        value="'+areaObj.model_id+'">'+areaObj.model_title+'</option>');  
    });
    });
    });        
</script>
```

View Page

```
 <div class="select-list-item">
      <select name="vehicle_model" class="vehicle_model">
            <option data-display="Select Model">Select Model</option>
            @foreach($vehiclemodel as $vehiclemodellist)
            <option value="{{ $vehiclemodellist->vehicle_model_id }}">{{ $vehiclemodellist->vehicle_model_title}}</option>
            @endforeach 
     </select>
 </div>
```

Please check the code, image and help me the issue solve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r09R8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
 $('.vehicle_model').append('<option                        
    value="'+areaObj.model_id+'">'+areaObj.model_title+'</option>');
```

to

```
$('.vehicle_model')[0].append('<option                        
    value="'+areaObj.model_id+'">'+areaObj.model_title+'</option>');
```

Comment: hi lavantho0508, Thanks for the reply. I have trying this code but the drop-down list not show .

Comment: You can refer to here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970120/option-not-append-in-select-in-jquery

Comment: Hi, Issue for owl.carousel.min.js that file.  After disabled that script , drop-down list is working now.